# Xcode 4.4.1 compile link error: file not found, but file exists?

Tags: ios5, xcode4, compiler-errors, file-not-found

This is what I did;

- Added a new entity do db-model and let modelbuilder create new subclass files.
- It asked to replace > OK > Files appear in file Navigator ok.
- Then dragged them (6) into a Model group folder > visible + checked file contest ok.

Then when trying to Build project again to simulator I got "Duplicate files...". I deleted all subclass files + empty trash > Rebuild files from model builder again.

Now one of the subclass-files x.m is missing?! Error can't compile...

> clang: error: no such file or directory:
>   '/Users/X/Documents/_iPhoneDev local/_CUSTOMER Projects/X/Version
>   0.2.5/X/Player.m' clang: error: no input files Command /Applications/Xcode
>   4.4.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   failed with exit code 1

Triyed this;

- In Organiser > projects > Deleted derived data.
- In Product > Clean (and alt+Project > Clean Build Folder)
- Deleted app from iPhone simulator.
- Rebuild projekt several times and done the above again.
- Even restarted my Mac!
- tried to revert to older screenshot from this morning, but Xcode crashed (!)
- Searched SO for simular issues and tips.

**Any ideas on have to save todays work? Or do I have to go back via TimeMachine?**

(FYi: Xcode 4.4.1 / Target iOS 5.1 / Nextlatest MBP fully packed...)